# How to use URI codes

Tags: uri

in 3rd line when i write   `"*444#"`  it works,  but when i write like this `"*#06#"` it does not work. please solve my problem

```js
public void onsam1click(View view)

{
String samimei = "*444#";
Intent intentsamimei = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
samimei = samimei.replace("*", Uri.encode("*")).replace("#", Uri.encode("#"));
Uri data = Uri.parse("tel:" + samimei);
intentsamimei.setData(data);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
return;
}
startActivity(intentsamimei);
}
```

Comment: What does not work? The replacing, the parsing, the setting, the condition? Does the compiler throws errors or is it just returning and the startActivity doesn't start?

Comment: when i write   "*444#"  it works and show me my balance..    but when i write "*#06#"  to show me the IMei Number of my cell phone it cant ,,,,

Comment: So you can't debug and don't get even compiler messages ... I am left in the dark.